# MvvmCross can't add second xaml view for other device family

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mvvmcross, uwp-xaml

In a UWP project you can add a new xaml view with the same name without the class background to create a specific view for a platform, for example mobile.

So I have my general view with code behind class:

PaymentListView.xaml and PaymentListView.xaml.cs.

And I wanted to create a new view for Mobile. So I created a XAML view with the name:
PaymentListView.DeviceFamily-Mobile.xaml

Both have the type views:MvxWindowsPage.

Now when I run the application, I get an exception on setup.Initialize:

```
Problem seen creating View-ViewModel lookup table - you have more than one View registered for the ViewModels: 2*PaymentListViewModel (PaymentListView,PaymentListView)'
```

Is there a way to solve this or do I have to make a giant Visual Trigger an press both UI's in one XAML?

Comment: Could you share a [MCVE] that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: I will make one and link it here.

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT I made an example and funnily it worked without any issues, so I looked what differences there are and found the issue in a missmatch between the class tag and the namespace of the code behind file (see the answer I posted). Thanks for the hint with making an example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During creating an example I found the issue.

I have all my views in a folder views. When I created a new XAML view in that folder the class path was something like this:

`x:Class="MoneyFox.Windows.PaymentListView"`

Therefore it wasn't correctly mapped to the PaymentListView.xaml.cs who has the namespace `MoneyFox.Windows.Views.PaymentListView`.
As soon as I adjusted that, it worked.